# How do I create a table using tbl command

Tags: roff

I have to create a table and I tried doing this using `tbl`

This is how the table should look:

[image]

But I can't find a way how to use the `tbl` command to create this table in a file called authors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what you tried and what result you got. Then we can help you to fix your code. Hint: The document *Lesk, M.E.: "TBL -- A Program to Format Tables"* contains several examples. You will probably find PDF versions if you search for the title.

Answer (score 1):

Using **nroff**:

```
nroff -t -Tascii
```

OR **groff**:

```
groff -t -Tascii
```

[ If you run into issues with `utf8` characters, try (for example) `groff -t -Tutf8` ].

Sample input from [Delete columns that contains only numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/687063/227738) , changing third line to `L L L L L L .` to `L`eft-align column headers are instead of  having them `c`enter-aligned (as noted by @they in the comments):

```
.TS
tab(@);
L L L L L L .
Nr.@Autor@Titlu@Cod@Tiraj@Tara
1@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 1@297485@11454@Germania
2@Gauss Carl@Aritmatica 2@297484@10254@Germania
3@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 3@297455@45872@Germania
.TE
```

Note, it's common to have a two-line column formatting string, one for the column header alignment, the second for the data format/alignment. Below designating `N` numeric vs `A` alphabetic column-alignment:

```
.TS
tab(@);
L L L L L L 
N A A N N A .
Nr.@Autor@Titlu@Cod@Tiraj@Tara
1@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 1@297485@11454@Germania
2@Gauss Carl@Aritmatica 2@297484@10254@Germania
3@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 3@297455@45872@Germania
.TE
```

See section **2.2. Format** of "Tbl — A Program to Format Tables" by
L. L. Cherry and M. E. Lesk for examples. Also, section **2.6  Invocation Examples** of [groff--The GNU implementation of troff](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/groff.pdf) by Trent A. Fisher and Werner Lemberg.