# Delete columns that contains only numbers

Tags: text-processing, sed, cut, roff

I have a table that containes some data and I need to delete the columns that contains only number (Nr.,Cod,Tiraj):

```
Nr.     Autor         Titlu        Cod     Tiraj     Tara
1    Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 1   297485   11454   Germania
2    Gauss Carl   Aritmatica 2   297484   10254   Germania
3    Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 3   297455   45872   Germania
```

The results should be like this:

```
Autor         Titlu         Tara
Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 1   Germania
Gauss Carl   Aritmatica 2   Germania
Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 3   Germania
```

The columns are separated by `TAB`

I created the table using this:

```
.TS
tab(@);
c c c c c c .
Nr.@Autor@Titlu@Cod@Tiraj@Tara
1@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 1@297485@11454@Germania
2@Gauss Carl@Aritmatica 2@297484@10254@Germania
3@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 3@297455@45872@Germania
.TE
```

Comment: How do you separate your columns? What is the format of your input file?

Comment: What is a number ? `-37`  ? `-37.3992` ? `-3.7264e-02` ? Is a blank column a number ? What if some of the columns contain numbers in some rows, non-numeric text in others and blanks in others ? How do you know when copying the column headers, which columns can contain numbers ?

Comment: If they are separated by tab, how come the headers are not aligned with the actual columns? Is it just a problem with copy/paste, or is there a different reason?

Comment: @aviro I added how I created the table.  It's a copy paste problem

Comment: (1) Do you need a solution that identifies the columns that contain only numeric values, or is it good enough to delete *columns 1, 4 and 5* (after manual / visual determination that they are the columns that contain numeric values)?  (2) Will you accept solutions that edit the `nroff` input rather than the output? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: When you said you wanted to delete columns that contain only numbers that is what most of us thought you meant, not that you just wanted to delete columns with headers Nr.,Cod,Tiraj as in the accepted answer which is a vastly simpler problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the `NR.`, `Cod` and `Tiraj` columns from a data set that is more or less CSV with some junk lines and using `@` as the field delimiter.

```bsh
sed -e 1,3d -e '$d' file |
csvcut -d @ -C 'Nr.,Cod,Tiraj' |
csvformat -D @
```

The output of this would be

```
Autor@Titlu@Tara
Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 1@Germania
Gauss Carl@Aritmatica 2@Germania
Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 3@Germania
```

Adding back what the `sed` removed and adjusting it for the new number of columns, and writing it to a new file:

```bsh
{
    printf '%s\n' .TS 'tab(@);' 'l l l .'
    sed -e 1,3d -e '$d' file |
    csvcut -d @ -C 'Nr.,Cod,Tiraj' |
    csvformat -D @
    echo .TE
} >file.new
```

The `csvcut` and `csvformat` utilities are part of csvkit, a toolkit for working with CSV files, available from https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The final table would be typeset using `nroff -t file.new`.

You could also get a variant of your table by just running the output of that initial pipeline though `column -s @ -t`:

```bsh
$ sed -e 1,3d -e '$d' file | csvcut -d @ -C 'Nr.,Cod,Tiraj' | csvformat -D @ | column -s @ -t
Autor       Titlu         Tara
Gauss Carl  Aritmetica 1  Germania
Gauss Carl  Aritmatica 2  Germania
Gauss Carl  Aritmetica 3  Germania
```

Or, you could use `csvlook`:

```bsh
$ sed -e 1,3d -e '$d' file | csvcut -d @ -C 'Nr.,Cod,Tiraj' | csvlook
| Autor      | Titlu        | Tara     |
| ---------- | ------------ | -------- |
| Gauss Carl | Aritmetica 1 | Germania |
| Gauss Carl | Aritmatica 2 | Germania |
| Gauss Carl | Aritmetica 3 | Germania |
```

... depending on what it is you *actually* want as output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this clumsy proof of concept. It's based on the assumption that columns are consistently numeric or non-numeric.

```
awk -F"\t" '
NR==1   {split($0, HDRSV)                                       # save header fields for later use
         next
        }
NR==2   {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  if ($i+0 != $i) PR[++IX] = i    # check if column is non-numeric and
                                                                # save col nr for print
         for (i=1; i<=IX; i++) printf "%s\t", HDRSV[PR[i]]      # print header fields
         printf ORS                                             # and line terminator
        }
        {for (i=1; i<=IX; i++) printf "%s\t", $PR[i]            # print each line´s fields
         printf ORS                                             # and line terminator
        }
' file
Autor   Titlu   Tara    
Gauss Carl  Aritmetica1 Germania    
Gauss Carl  Aritmatica2 Germania    
Gauss Carl  Aritmetica3 Germania
```

Comment: you have an extra empty column at the end of each line; see `awk .... | cat -A`

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ cat authors.tr | raku -ne '.split( / [^ | \S] [\d+]+ %% "\@" /, :skip-empty).join("\@").put;' | raku -ne '++$ == 4 ?? .split("\@")[1,2,5].join("\@").put !! .put;' | nroff -t -Tascii
```

Sample Input:

```
TS
tab(@);
c c c c c c .
Nr.@Autor@Titlu@Cod@Tiraj@Tara
1@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 1@297485@11454@Germania
2@Gauss Carl@Aritmatica 2@297484@10254@Germania
3@Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 3@297455@45872@Germania
.TE
```

Sample Output:

```
  Autor         Titlu         Tara
Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 1   Germania
Gauss Carl   Aritmatica 2   Germania
Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 3   Germania
```

As a challenge I decided to try writing a Raku one-liner (well, two-liner: one for the header plus one for the data columns) that would modify the `authors.tr` nroff/groff source file. One tricky aspect is that it's difficult to determine if an entire field is composed of only digits: certainly the internal (non-leftmost/non-rightmost) columns will be surrounded by column separators, but the terminal (leftmost/rightmost) won't.

I finally hit upon the fact that (at least for the columns given) the first regex atom should be `[^ | \S]`. The remainder of regex is handled by Raku's nifty `%%` "modified quantifier", which recognizes repeating (column-wise) patterns, like `[\d+]+ %% "\t"`, which means *'one-or-more-columns-of-`\d+`-separated-by-tabs-allowing-trailing-tab'*. The regex above deletes any columns ending in digits, excepting those columns containing whitespace immediately preceding (like the `Aritmetica 1` column).

But really, this is way too much work. Much simpler to:

1. delete the `.` period at the end of line_#3 and insert a new line_#4 in
   the nroff/groff column format section, which designates `N` numeric vs `A` alphabetic (non-header, data)
   columns,
2. parse the header with Raku (example below using `N A A N N A .`
   as new line_#4), and
3. delete those columns that are designated `N`.

```perl
~$ cat authors2.tr  |  raku -e 'my @a=lines; \
    @a[2..3] = @a[2..3]>>.comb>>.[0,2,4...*];    \
    @a[4..7].=map: *.split("\@", :skip-empty);   \
    my $n    = @a[3].grep({!/ N /}, :k ).list;   \
    @a[2]    = @a[2][ |$n.head(*-1)];  @a[3] = @a[3][ |$n];  \
    @a[4..7].=map: *.[ |$n.head(*-1)].join("\@");  .put for @a;'
```

Sample Output (valid nroff/groff):

```
.TS
tab(@);
c c c
A A A .
Autor@Titlu@Tara
Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 1@Germania
Gauss Carl@Aritmatica 2@Germania
Gauss Carl@Aritmetica 3@Germania
.TE
```

Sample Output (after `nroff -t -Tascii`):

```
  Autor         Titlu         Tara
Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 1   Germania
Gauss Carl   Aritmatica 2   Germania
Gauss Carl   Aritmetica 3   Germania
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

If want to make sure that ALL of the fields in the specific column are numbers, this is a bit clunky, but it works.

```
# cat remove_number_fields.awk
NR==1 {
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
    cols[i]=0
} 
NR > 1 {
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
    if ($i+0 == $i) 
      cols[i]=1
} 
END {
  CMD=sprintf ("awk -F $'\\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {print ")
  for (i=1;i<=length(cols);i++) 
    if (cols[i] == 0)
    {
      CMD = CMD sprintf ("$%d", i)
      if (i < length(cols)-1)
        CMD = CMD sprintf (",")
    }
  CMD = CMD sprintf ("}' %s\n", FILENAME)
  print "Going to run the following command:", CMD
  system(CMD)
}
```

Since after it finished reading the file it needs to read it from the beginning (and this time removing the numeral fields), so it actually generates a new `awk` command and prints it to the screen...

```
# awk -F $'\t' -f remove_number_fields.awk inputfile
Going to run the following command: awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {print $2,$3,$6}' inputfile

Autor   Titlu   Tara
Gauss Carl      Aritmetica 1    Germania
Gauss Carl      Aritmatica 2    Germania
Gauss Carl      Aritmetica 3    Germania
```

I'm sure that there's more elegant way somewhere, but that's what I came up with.

Comment: why do you call another awk command within awk script? you cannot simply print what you found?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i != ($i+0) ) {
                isGood[i]
            }
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    out = sep = ""
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( i in isGood ) {
            out = out sep $i
            sep = OFS
        }
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
Autor   Titlu   Tara
Gauss Carl      Aritmetica 1    Germania
Gauss Carl      Aritmatica 2    Germania
Gauss Carl      Aritmetica 3    Germania
```